# Spring JPA @QueryHint ignored for lock timeout?

Tags: concurrency, spring-data-jpa, locking

I have a query in a Spring data JpaRepository like so:

```
@Lock(value = LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = "javax.persistence.lock.timeout", value = "70000")})
Collection<AnyCLass> findBy ...
```

However, in my test, if I run the transaction ( that uses this query as the first query) in two concurrent threads I get an SQL Lock timeout (`SQL Error: 50200, SQLState: HYT00`) after one second, which is the default for the H2 in memory.
If the transaction is faster then one second everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround for this Issue is a simple retry on the enclosing method:

```
@Retryable(backoff = @Backoff(value = 500,random = true))
void getSometingLocked(){
 findById(id)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That’s what we do already. The question was more about the fact that the hint is ignored. This however turned out to be normal behavior for many databases.

Comment: @PeMa could you elaborate more about this being the "default behavior"?
I'm using PostgreSQL and running into this issue with Spring Data. However, using the EntityManager directly it works as expected.

Comment: @H.Schulz I am not sure, what exactly you mean by "using the entity manager directly". If you configure the entity manager, you might have configured another lock timeout. Generally speaking, it turned out, that most databases ignore the query hint. They rather respect flags, that are set in the connection string. Without any flags being set, H2 (default in-memory database for testing) has a lock timeout of 2 seconds, while MariaDB has 30 (if I remember correctly). I don't know about PostgreSQL but you might have different behaviours when using H2 in your test and PostgreSQL in production.

Comment: @PeMa I mean using `entityManager.createQuery().setLockMode(PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT).setHint("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 25000).getSingleResult()` does the `select for update` without the `nowait` option and using a spring-data-jpa repository like in the question does it with the `nowait`, i.e. ignores the query hint.

Comment: @H.Schulz Well in this case, it sounds like a bug in springs JPA implementation. Maybe you can raise a bug report there. https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJPA/issues/DATAJPA-1686?filter=allopenissues